# passing results from <div id="bcode"></div> to the next line

Tags: javascript, html

I made a simple page for queries but cannot link between the `<div id="bcode"></div>` and the form which shows below:

```
<html><head>
        <meta http-equiv="onallkeys" content="Javascript:doKeys('%s');">
        <meta http-equiv="all_decoders" content="enabled">
        <meta http-equiv="scannernavigate" content="Javascript:doScan('%s');">
        <meta http-equiv="scanner" content="enabled">
        <!--meta HTTP-Equiv="upce0" Content="enabled">
        <meta HTTP-Equiv="upca" Content="enabled">
        <meta HTTP-Equiv="upce0-ConvertToupca" Content="true">
        <meta HTTP-Equiv="ean8" Content="enabled">
        <meta HTTP-Equiv="ean13" Content="enabled">
        <meta HTTP-Equiv="ean8-ConvertToEAN13" Content="true"-->
        <meta http-equiv="scanner" content="AIM_TYPE_PRESENTATION">
</head> 
<BODY onLoad="doSoftScan();">
  <SCRIPT LANGAUGE="JavaScript">
    var Generic = new ActiveXObject("SymbolBrowser.Generic");


    function doSoftScan()
    {
     Generic.InvokeMetaFunction('scanner', 'start');
    }


    function doScan(data)
    {
     bcode.innerHTML = 'Scanned Code:<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;' + data;
     setTimeout("doSoftScan()", 1250);
   }
  </SCRIPT>
  <div id="bcode"></div>
  <form method="post" action="search_display.php?go" id="bcode">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried it to my MK500, it scans but cannot focus to textbox and show.
I am a newbie for this html programming and perhaps you can shed some light on this segment.

Regards,
Bert

Comment: What do you mean by link? Place the form inside?

Comment: Cannot have duplicate `id=bcode` ids must be unique.  Assign ids to inputs, make an onfocus event as a method of Generic since it's an Object.

Comment: Without the form, it will just show the scanned barcode on the page.  I wanted to use that line or result will link to the form and gives result from search_display.php...

Comment: If I am going to change the id from the form then it will not be link to <div id="bcode"> logically... I want to have it like that but I have limited idea on html/javascript.

Comment: you can try `<output id="bc" for="bcode"></output>` instead of `<div id="bcode"></div>` I'm just going to post an answer, but keep in mind I'm going blind into this. I haven't used a zebra bcode program since 1997.

Comment: I tried like this:    


<output id="bc" for="bcode"></output>
  <form method="post" action="search_display.php?go" id="bcode">
  <input type="text" name="name" onfocus="doSoftScan()">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
 </form>


but cannot open to search_display.php